# Conditional summation in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, conditional-statements, formula

I have some rows with a price and quantity and I'm looking to sum only the prices where the quantity > 5

```
itemname        price         Qty
----------------------------------
apple            20            2
watermelon       10            3
bango            22            6
hashesh           3            9
```

Given the above data, the sum I'd like to get is 22+3=25. How do I write a formula to do this?

Answer (score 9):

create a formula field named `calculation` to the side of quantity and enter the following text:

```
// {@calculation}
If quantity>5 then price
else 0
```

now take the sum of `{@calculation}`.  suppress both detail in the report.

Take the sum and place in the footer of the required column.