# Sum(Field) Where Condition=Value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm trying to find how should be the correct syntax for Sum(FIELD) where field Condition=Value 
I'm using this code;

```
 if ({VatCodes.VatValue} =12) then Sum({InventoryTransTemp.Price})
```

The problem is that this syntax works but for all my report fields and either contain this value or not.My syntax in sql server is Select Sum(InventoryTransTemp.Price) where Vatcodes.VatValues=12.

How should i write it for succedd my desired result?

Comment: I see here problem is with syntax also where are you placing the formula in report. To answer this question you need to provide more input about what are you trying to do in report

Comment: @bhow In crystal reports comparison is done with `=`

Comment: Note for future users: I am not sure what the OP is trying to achieve but if you are looking for conditional sum (i.e. consider the row for sum only if condition match) then [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22483434/1369235).