# Conditional Sum in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I know that my question is very basic but I am new to Crystal Reports, therefore, I stuck in one of crystal report formula.i will be very thankful if someone helps me that what formula should I use for the following SQL query to return the sum of selected rows:
    select sum(credithr) from transcript_detail_pr where checkid is null
I am using the below statement in the formula
    if isnull({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CheckId})= true
    then sum({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CreditHr})

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
if isnull({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CheckId})
then 
sum({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CreditHr})
else 
0
```

Comment: many thanks for your prompt response I tried the below code but does not restrict summation  if isnull({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CheckId})
then 
sum ({Transcript_Detail_Pr.CreditHr})
else 
0

Comment: can you please check with removing sum aggregation from that and then use it

Comment: many thanks, i solved it, found help on below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483434/conditional-summation-in-crystal-reports